A useState set within a useffect is not changing the value of the constant
When trying to make a private route in React the True Returned Value from Promise Usarauthenticateduser (), within Useeeffect is not changing the value of Isauthenticated. What can I do to correct the error?
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import UserServices from '../Services/UserService';
import { Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const userService = new UserServices();

export default function ProtectedRoutesUser({ children }) {
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        async function checkAuthentication() {
            try {
                const authenticated = await userService.userAutheticatedUser();
                setIsAuthenticated(authenticated);
            } catch (error) {
                console.error(error);
            }
        }
        checkAuthentication();
    }, [isAuthenticated]);
    
    return isAuthenticated ? children : <Navigate to="/login" />;
}



I was waiting for you to return the child element or not

Effects do not run on the server, if that's what you're asking.
